# Lines and connection in the plane?

Tags: general-topology

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}^*$ and $f(n)$ be a strictly decreasing function such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(n)=0$. Let moreover $L_n$ be the line described by the equation $y=cx+f(n)$. Is it true that
$$
\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} L_n
$$
is a connected set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I have no clue. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried sketching an example, say $f(n)=\frac{1}{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set in question and
$\epsilon = {1 \over 3} \min (f(1)-f(0), f(0)-f(-1))$.

Let $U = \{ (x,y) | y-cx - f(0) < \epsilon \}$,
$V = \{ (x,y) | y-cx - f(0) > \epsilon \}$.

We see that $U,V$ are open, disjoint and $A \subset U \cup V$ and $A$ has
a non empty intersection with $U,V$.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't connected since all of the lines are parallel and $0<f(n_1)<f(n_2)$ for all $n_1>n_2$.